# Is it possible to prove all main integral properties for the discreet sum integral formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation, alternative-proof

There are a ton of different formulas for integrals, and my favourite is one I often hear called the discreet sum integral, defined such that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{d\to0^+}\sum_{x=a/d}^{b/d}df(dx)$$
or, sometimes
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{d\to\infty}\sum_{x=ad}^{bd}d^{-1}f(x/d)$$
This is the formula that's typically used for numerical integration (where instead of calculating the integral, you just approximate it by using a sufficently small/large value of $d$ and calculating discreetly, since that's way easier to program). However, I've never seen the main integral properties proven in this form.

Of course, the phrase "main integral property" is a bit vague, but I'm reffering to things such as $\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx$, $\int_a^af(x)dx=0$, $\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_b^cf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx$, integration by parts, etcetera.

Is that because this form is a bit unwieldy, so it's hard to prove them? Or is it impossible? Or is proving these things actually pretty easy, and I've just missed it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The first two follow from the third. To prove the third, use that $\lim (a_n + b_n) = \lim a_n + \lim b_n$; i.e, that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits when the limits $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exist.

Comment: @William That's true. I mean the general set of integral properties *like* those. The sort that would be considered "basic" properties of integrals, not just those four things.

Comment: Grammar tip:  When you are referring to a set of isolated points or to a countable set of points, you should use the word *discrete*.  The word *discreet* means to be careful not to cause embarrassment or to attract too much attention.

Comment: @SigMoid Your comment makes me unsure about what your question actually is? As suggested by my comment, a large portion of fundamental integral identities can be proved by (1.) showing the discrete form is true, and (2.) showing the identity holds in the limit. Is your question about *which* integral identities can be proved this way?

Comment: @William Yes. I'm asking which of the common integral properties are provable from the discrete integral. I'm sorry if I made that unclear.